# capephp, Imagick: Internal Error - No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2709

Tags: cakephp, imagick

In a cakephp based image converter page I get the above error message. I don't really understand what changed. The page worked without any problem.
Where is the issue source located? It's maybe a typical issue. Thanks!

unable to open image `img/uefa2016/uploaded/KRRXXK5S.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2709

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
Stack Trace

```
APP/Controller/ProfileGeneratorController.php line 506 → Imagick->readimage(string)
APP/Controller/ProfileGeneratorController.php line 380 → ProfileGeneratorController->page(string, array, string)
[internal function] → ProfileGeneratorController->fociebhu()
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 490 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(ProfileGeneratorController, array)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 193 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 167 → Dispatcher->_invoke(ProfileGeneratorController, CakeRequest)
APP/webroot/index.php line 96 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```